Are complete and totally proper forcing the same?
See this question for the definition of totally proper forcing, which is confusingly called strongly proper in Cummings' handbook chapter (which clashes with the more recent notion of strong properness due to Mitchell).
There is also the notion of complete forcing invented by Shelah; see for example Definition 2.2.1 of On subcomplete forcings by Minden. It says if: (i) $\theta$ is large enough, (ii) $N\prec H(\theta)$ is countable and contains $\mathbb{P}$, (iii) $\overline{N}$ is the transitive collapse of $N$ and $\overline{\mathbb{P}}$ is the image of $\mathbb{P}$, (iv) $\sigma:\overline{N}\rightarrow H(\theta)$ is the inverse collapse, (v) $\overline{G}$ is (in $V$, I think) $\mathbb{\overline{P}}$-generic over $\overline{N}$, then there exists $p\in\mathbb{P}$ forcing $\sigma''\overline{G}\subseteq G$.
Questions:

Does the definition of completeness change if we require $p$ to be a lower bound of $\sigma''\overline{G}$?

Are completeness and total properness the same? Part of the reason I ask this is that in Goldstern's A taste of proper forcing he refers to a totally $(N,\mathbb{P})$ generic condition $p$ as "$N$-complete". Completeness is up to forcing equivalence the same as $\sigma$-closed (Theorem 2.2.14 of Minden), while totally proper is the same as proper and $\sigma$-distributive (Proposition 3.3 of this paper). So we can rephrase this question as: is there a proper and $\sigma$-distributive forcing that is not equivalent to a $\sigma$-closed forcing?



There is some conflict in the literature regarding the usage of "totally" and "complete" to denote the same concept. I think "totally proper" is the slightly more common term, that is the approach taken, for example, in Abraham's handbook chapter, which is probably the standard reference for elementary proper forcing (i.e. if whatever you're trying to accomplish doesn't require the higher sorcery that is in Shelah's book).
To clarify, the set $\overline G$ is in the ground model $V$; your thinking is correct.
Lets assume now that $P$ is separative, which is what one usually does when working with total properness (because of Proposition 3.3 in the Eisworth-Roitman paper you linked). Suppose that we required that $p\le \sigma''\overline G$. I claim that then $\sigma''\overline G=\{q\in N\cap P:p\le q\}$. Indeed, the assumption $p\le \sigma''\overline G$ yields the $\subseteq$ inclusion. To see the other one, we use:
Fact: Let $M$ be a transitive model of (enough) set theory, $Q\in M$ a poset and $F\subset Q$ a filter which is $Q$-generic over $M$. Then $F$ is a maximal filter in $Q$.
Proof: Let $F'\subset P$ be a filter with $F\subseteq F'$ and suppose $p\in F'\setminus F$. Let $$D=\{q\in Q:q\le p \vee q\perp p\}.$$
One can check that $D$ is dense in $P$ and $D\in M$ because $M$ is sufficiently closed. By genericity, $D\cap F\neq \emptyset$. Fix $q\in D$. If $q\le p$ then $p\in F$, which is false, hence $q\perp p$. But $q,p\in F'$ and $F'$ is a filter, contradiction.$\square$
Now apply the fact with $M=\overline{N}$, $Q=\overline{P}$ and $F=\bar G$ to conclude that $\overline G=\sigma^{-1}[\{q\in N\cap P:p\le q\}]$. Here we are tacitly using the elementarity of $N$ to infer that $\{q\in N\cap P:p\le q\}$ is a filter in the poset $N\cap P$ hence gets pulled back by $\sigma$ into a filter on $\overline N$.
To summarize, requiring that $p$ be a lower bound just gives you ordinary total properness.
For an example of a totally proper poset that is not forcing equivalent to a countably closed poset, one can specialize an Aronszajn tree with a totally proper poset. This can't be forcing equivalent to a countably closed poset if the original tree was Suslin.

Thanks for the detailed answer. My first question was actually whether the definition changes if we further require $p$ to be a lower bound of $\sigma``\overline{G}$, but I guess it's equivalent by your argument.

Could you explain why $P$ is not equivalent to any $\sigma$-closed poset (rather than just not being $\sigma$-closed itself)? I realize that forcing with a Suslin tree is ccc (hence proper) and $\sigma$-distributive, and cannot be equivalent to a $\sigma$-closed forcing since a nontrivial $\sigma$-closed forcing has an antichain of size continuum, and chain condition is forcing invariant.

@newaccount Having thought about it some more, I'm actually not sure now. I've added a (consistent) example, namely the Shelah's poset to specialize a Suslin tree without adding reals.

Isn't a Suslin tree itself a consistent example? A Suslin tree viewed as a forcing poset is $\sigma$-distributive by Lemma IV.6.6 in Kunen.

@newaccount Yeah, a Suslin tree works too, I was trying to construct an example in ZFC and got tunnel vision.
